# is Adobe flash professional cs5 mac projector (.app) and iphone application (.app) same or not?

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

i tried to developed iphone application using adobe flash professional cs5 in windows so i bought iphone digital certification and etc , when i move to app store they asked app format application so i tried to publish as app format using adobe flash cs5 . But i don’t know is it same? but it also publish ipa format .( App store support ipa format or not ) Let me know ?
Could u clear my doubt please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mac projector is a standalone executable targeting desktop mac OS - it doesn't have anything to do with iPhones. When developing iPhone apps from CS5, the .IPA file that you get out of Flash is the final form of the application as far as Flash is concerned. Everything after that (i.e. getting that ipa onto a phone or into the iTunes store) is done with Apple's tools and services.

**However** - you should be aware that creating iPhone apps with Flash CS5 is probably not a good idea. Technically they work fine, but earlier this year Apple [changed its legal stuff](http://www.engadget.com/2010/04/08/apples-iphone-lockdown-apps-must-be-written-in-one-of-three-la/) to require that apps be "originally written" in objective C, etc.

In other words you can create your app with Flash, and it should work fine if you put it on your own device via ad-hoc installation, but if you submit it to the iTunes store Apple will reject it (presumably at least, according to how most people interpret their SDK agreement).

Answer (score 1):

On Sep 9 Apple 2010 Apple [relaxed their restrictions](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html) on the development tools used to create iOS apps.

Adobe’s Packager for iPhone compiles ActionScript 3.0 bytecode into native iPhone application code. These apps can now be distributed as iPhone application installer files (.ipa files)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe flash is not supported on iPhone and probably will not make it anytime soon according to [Steve Jobs](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/).

Comment: He's asking about Flash CS5's ability to create native iPhone apps, not general flash content.